# Spring Cloud Circuit Breaker: Feign doesn't open circuit breaker

Tags: java, spring-cloud, feign, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

Circuit breaker works, fallback is called, but circuit breaker doesn't change it's state and every time send request to failed service.
Tried the same YAML config with rest template - works correctly.

Feign client

```java
@FeignClient(
        name = MyFeignClient.SERVICE_NAME,
        url = "https://httpbin.org/",
        configuration = {FeignClientConfiguration.class})
public interface MyFeignClient {
    String SERVICE_NAME = "producer-service";

    @GetMapping(value = "/status/502")
    ResponseEntity<String> gerRequest();
}
```

Fallback class

```java
public class MyFallback implements MyFeignClient {
    private final Exception cause;

    public MyFallback(Exception cause) {
        this.cause = cause;
    }

    public ResponseEntity<String> gerRequest() {
        if (cause instanceof HttpServerErrorException){
            return ResponseEntity.of(Optional.of(cause.getMessage()));
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.of(Optional.of(cause.getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

Feign client configuration

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FeignClientConfiguration {
    private final CircuitBreakerRegistry registry;

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Feign.Builder feignBuilder() {
        CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = registry.circuitBreaker("producer-service");
        FeignDecorators decorators = FeignDecorators.builder()
                .withCircuitBreaker(circuitBreaker)
                .withFallbackFactory(MyFallback::new)
                .build();
        return Resilience4jFeign.builder(decorators);
    }
}
```

Circuit breaker YAML config

```yaml
resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
  configs:
    default:
      registerHealthIndicator: true
      slidingWindowType: COUNT_BASED
      slidingWindowSize: 5
      minimumNumberOfCalls: 3
      permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 1
      automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled: true
      waitDurationInOpenState: 5s
      failureRateThreshold: 50
      eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
      writableStackTraceEnabled: true
      recordExceptions:
        - org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException
        - java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        - java.io.IOException
    shared:
      slidingWindowSize: 100
      permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 30
      waitDurationInOpenState: 1s
      failureRateThreshold: 50
      eventConsumerBufferSize: 10
  instances:
    producer-service:
      baseConfig: default
```